# django portlets

Tags: python, django, django-templates, portlet

im new to django and developing my first website on it but cant find out how to have multiple views displayed on a given template.
I also was hoping there was something similar to porlets in django so that you could easily create a application and place it on different pages without duplicate code.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template you use for any given view is passed as an argument in the response that is returned by a view method (or if you are using class-based views it is set explicitly). So all you would have to do is return the same template on various views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def view_1(request):
    return render(request, 'same_template.html', {})
def view_2(request):
    return render(request, 'same_teamplate.html', {})
```

More on writing views [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/) and how to use render [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/)

If the data for the second part of your question is dynamic then this could be handled in some sort of middleware, or you could have a view that returns a json response, which would be accessed via an ajax call.

If the data is static then just look into extending templates / the django templating language [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)